# Ubuntu guest, OSX host - cannot connect guest to internet

Tags: macos, ubuntu, networking, virtualbox

I have a Virtualbox instance running the latest Ubuntu hosted on OSX. Things worked fine until today when, for no apparent reason, Ubuntu stopped raising the network card on startup.

I've fiddled with all network options in VirtualBox but nothing seems to work.

How can I troubleshoot this?

**Added as suggested:**

I can see eth0, but it has no IP is assigned. Could the problem be with the router, to which I do not have access?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does the host still have Internet connectivity?
Then traceroute to somewhere outside of your network - Google, f/ex - and see where the failures begin.

Edit:
Someone may be able suggest a debug path, but if you care more about getting the broken VM working than understanding why it doesn't, you can make a new VM, confirm it can communicate, then use its net settings to re-configure the currently broken VM.

Comment: Host is fine. The problem is that when ubuntu boots up fails to start the network cards. I can see eth0, but it has no IP assigned.

Comment: This would be useful to add to your question, along with anything else you've learned about the issue that might help someone help you.

Answer (score 0):

If your OSX Host still has networking, and you don't see any IP address on the interface, I'd guess networking somehow got hosed on Ubuntu.

Could you run [dhclient](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/lucid/man8/dhclient3.8.html)? see if that gives you an address.

Answer (score 0):

I too had the exact same issue, Ubuntu client and OSX host. The problem was DHCP stopped working for an unknown reason. I had to switch to static IP assignment. Then I switched to Vmware Fusion.

Comment: I just installed a new image. Fixed everything.